Build status is not published to GitLab server
I have a self-hosted environment that include:

Jenkins version 2.440.2 running on Linux 5.10.0-30-amd64
GitLab-CE version 17.1.1 running on Linux 6.6.32-current-rockchip

Until recent GitLab-CE update to 17.x Jenkins build results have been posted to GitLab server and were correctly reflected in commit status. However, GitLab-CE no longer allow access tokens with indefinite validity period - as result all GitLab related credentials stored in Jenkins became invalid. As final result all build jobs are successfully triggered by GitLab via webhook configured in the job, source code successfully accessed and checked out from GitLab but post-build action “Publish build status to GitLab” failed with message
No GitLab connection configured
Jenkins setup:
Access to GitLab is configured in two sections of Jenkins System:

GitLab Connections section with following: Enable authentication for ‘/project’ end-point = off; Credentials → API Token for accessing GitLab
GitLab Servers section with following: Credentials → The Personal Access Token for GitLab APIs access
All connections are successful when tested.

GitLab related plugins installed:

Generic Webhook Trigger Plugin Version2.2.2
GitLab Plugin Version1.8.1
GitLab API Plugin Version5.3.0-91.v1f9a_fda_d654f
GitLab Branch Source Plugin Version704.vc7f1202d7e14
Gitlab Merge Request Builder Version2.0.0

I’ll be very grateful if community help me to resolve my problem.
I've tried different credentials but it didn't resolve this problem
Regards,
Nick
